# How to default a value in a column if the ID, Date and Amount values are duplicated in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2017 version.

I want to default a column to a specific value if the ID, Date and Amount values are duplicated.

Example: if you see in the below table ID, Date and Amount values are duplicated, and based on that I need to default `Priority` value to `Priority1`.

```
ID   DATE         AMOUNT  PRIORITY    DEPARTMENT
7    01/01/2020   100     Priority 1  IT
7    01/01/2020   100     Priority 2  HR
```

I used the following statement,

```
UPDATE TABLE T
SET PRIORITY = 'Priority 1'
GROUP BY T.PRIORITY
WHERE ID =  (SELECT ID FROM T
GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID)>1)
and DATE =  (SELECT DATE FROM T
GROUP BY DATE HAVING(COUNT (DATE))>1)
and AMOUNT =  (SELECT AMOUNT FROM T
GROUP BY AMOUNT HAVING(COUNT (AMOUNT))>1)
```

and it returned the following error.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: I tried a case, and update statements but I couldn't come up with a solid logic to make it work. Updates are done manually, and main purpose of this is to find duplicate ID, Date and Amount records and default priority value to the highest one.

Comment: I used the following update statement

UPDATE TABLE T
SET PRIORITY = 'Priority 1'
GROUP BY T.PRIORITY
WHERE ID =  (SELECT ID FROM T
GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID)>1)
and DATE =  (SELECT DATE FROM T
GROUP BY DATE HAVING(COUNT (DATE))>1) 
and AMOUNT =  (SELECT AMOUNT FROM T
GROUP BY AMOUNT HAVING(COUNT (AMOUNT))>1)

and it returned the following error,

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set it as part of your insert:

```
declare @Id int, @Date date, @Amount money, @Piority varchar(12);

insert into dbo.MyTable (id, [Date], Amount, Prority)
    select @Id, @Date, @Amount, case when exists (select 1 from dbo.MyTable where id = @Id and [Date] = @Date and Amount = @Amount) then 'Priority 1' else @Priority end;
```

Otherwise find the duplicate rows and update them:

```
update T set
    [Priority] = 'Priority1'
from dbo.MyTable T
inner join (
    select id, [Date], Amount
    from dbo.MyTable
    group by id, [Date], Amount
    having count(*) > 1
) D on D.id = T.id and T.[Date] = D.[Date] and T.Amount = D.Amountl
```

Comment: Hello Dale, I have around 9 fields and nearly 10k records in the table, and I just included a few of them as an example, can I use the same code you provided? and will it work for my table with more fields and more records?

Comment: Firstly, please ensure your question accurately reflects your problem. Secondly why did you edit your attempt back out of your question? Thirdly, you need to understand what the query I have written does and then you will be able to answer your own question. Please do not run code you do not understand. If you need help understand it, then ask that.

Comment: I removed the code by mistake, and thanks for your suggestions, and I think I got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have duplicated values, create a unique constraint and leave the work to the SQL Server. Then you can catch an error either in the SQL Server or in the .net (or other language) and inform the user a duplicated record cannot be inserted.

It is more convenient than letting the user thinks the data is committed but actually the data is transformed.

If you need to count the duplicates, add counter column.

If your business logic require such behavior you may look to [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and create `INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE` trigger which basically allows you to execute T-SQL code before the changes are committed. There you can can for duplicates and if such exists to modify the values and insert them.